# Console.log in a custom .map function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've grabbed some data from redux and am mapping to a component.

If I console.log the text attribute, I do recieve all the data available. See below:
https://gyazo.com/ae7167952d14623be30f80b69cc20d5c

However I would like to link this to an onClick event. E.g if I click on 'Data Analyst', this will console.log -> Data Analyst. This however is not functioning and I am getting zero response from these events.

What is incorrect on my syntax?

```
    const searchResults = useSelector(state => state.jobsearch.roles.map(role => role.title))

    const SearchResultsText = ({ text }) => {
        console.log(text)
        
        return (
            <JobContainer onClick={() => console.log(text)}>
                <JobSearchTypography 
                >
                    {text}
                </JobSearchTypography>
          </JobContainer>
        );
      };
```

When it's in the app itself, it looks as such:

```
                <JobContainer >
                {searchResults && searchResults.length < 3 && searchResults.map((result) =>
                    (<IndividualContainer >
                        <SearchResultsText text={result}/>
                    </IndividualContainer>
                    )
                )}
                </JobContainer>
```

Comment: You should apply onclick not on the jobcontainer,instead apply it to your list item

Comment: Hi @Gulshan, what is the list item, can you please copy code?

Comment: can you show your searchResultText component?

Comment: Hi Gulshan, search results is:     const SearchResultsText = ({ role }) => {
        return (
            <JobContainer>
                <JobSearchTypography 
                 onClick={() => console.log('role')}>
                    {role} 
                </JobSearchTypography>
          </JobContainer>
        );
      };

Comment: which css framwork are you using?

Comment: styled components

Comment: you shold apply onclick to  JobSearchTypography component and then try?

Comment: Thanks Gulshan but this doesn't fix anything. The data still wont consoel.log. Regardless of what part i put it on.

Answer (score 0):

If your text is inside `JobSearchTypography`  then you can try it something like this-

```js
<JobSearchTypography  onClick={(e)=>console.log(e.target.innerHTML)}>
      {text}
</JobSearchTypography>
```